# R: Subsetting matrix based on another matrix and running rle

Tags: r, matrix, apply

Sample data:

```
      year <- rep(1980:2015, each = 365) 
      doy <- rep(1:365, times = 36)

      set.seed(125) 
      val <- sample(0:1, size = 365*36,replace = TRUE) 
      mat <- as.matrix(cbind(year,doy,val))
```

`mat` is data with years, doy and a value column which is either 1 or 0.

I have another matrix `mat1`.

```
      set.seed(123) 
      mat1 <- apply(matrix(sample(c(230:365), replace = TRUE, size = 4L * 36L), nrow = 36L), 2L, sort)
      mat1 <- t(apply(mat1, 1, function(x) x[order(x)]))
      head(mat1)

            [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
      [1,]  230  231  233  236
      [2,]  235  238  242  242
      [3,]  236  242  243  246
      [4,]  243  245  247  249
      [5,]  247  248  249  250
      [6,]  249  250  253  263
```

`mat1` also has 36 rows each for corresponding year in `mat`.`mat1` contains some doy in four columns for each year.

I want to subset each year from `mat` using `mat1`. For example, year 1980 in `mat` is to be 
subsetted in three groups:

```
      group 1 from 230 till 231 (1st and second column of row 1 from `mat1`)
      group 2 from 232 till 233 (second column + 1 to third column of row 1 from `mat1`)
      group 3 from 234 till 236 (third column + 1 to fourth column of row 1 from `mat1`)
```

This will give me three vectors for 1980. I want to do an rle on each vector to find the longest
consecutive occurrence of 1. Something like

```
       group1.rle <- rle(group1)
       group2.rle <- rle(group2)
       group3.rle <- rle(group3)

       max(group1.rle$lengths[group1.rle$values == 1])
       max(group2.rle$lengths[group2.rle$values == 1])
       max(group3.rle$lengths[group3.rle$values == 1])
```

and then repeat this for all the years `mat`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a little bit overdone, but I got carried away in the tidyverse (who doesn't know that feeling? ;) )

**Packages**

```
# You might as well go with library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
```

**Code & Explanation**

```
# Preparation
mat <- as.data.frame(mat)
colnames(mat1) <- c("D1", "D2", "D3", "D4")
mat1 <- cbind(year = 1980:2015, mat1)
mat1 <- as.data.frame(mat1)
```

I name the columns of `mat1`, add the column `year` and turn both `mat` and `mat1` into nice `tibble`s so I use `left_join` on them. This is important to get the right indicator columns for the right years.

```
mat_new <- mat %>% 
  left_join(mat1, by = "year") %>% 
  mutate(group1 = (doy >= D1 & doy <=D2), 
         group2 = (doy >= D2 + 1 & doy <=D3),  
         group3 = (doy >= D3  + 1 & doy <=D4)) 

mat_new

# A tibble: 13,140 x 10
#     year   doy   val    D1    D2    D3    D4 group1 group2 group3
#    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>
#  1  1980     1     1   230   231   233   236  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
#  2  1980     2     0   230   231   233   236  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
#  3  1980     3     0   230   231   233   236  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
#  4  1980     4     0   230   231   233   236  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
#  5  1980     5     1   230   231   233   236  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
#  6  1980     6     1   230   231   233   236  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
#  7  1980     7     1   230   231   233   236  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
#  8  1980     8     0   230   231   233   236  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
#  9  1980     9     1   230   231   233   236  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
# 10  1980    10     1   230   231   233   236  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
# ... with 13,130 more rows
```

So first join the two `tibble` and then add group columns whether the `doy` is in the subset.

```
mat_new <- mat_new %>% 
  gather(group, indicator, group1:group3) %>% 
  nest(doy, val, indicator) 

mat_new

# A tibble: 108 x 7
# year    D1    D2    D3    D4  group               data
# <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <chr>             <list>
#  1  1980   230   231   233   236 group1 <tibble [365 x 3]>
#  2  1981   235   238   242   242 group1 <tibble [365 x 3]>
#  3  1982   236   242   243   246 group1 <tibble [365 x 3]>
#  4  1983   243   245   247   249 group1 <tibble [365 x 3]>
#  5  1984   247   248   249   250 group1 <tibble [365 x 3]>
#  6  1985   249   250   253   263 group1 <tibble [365 x 3]>
#  7  1986   250   250   255   269 group1 <tibble [365 x 3]>
#  8  1987   255   258   259   269 group1 <tibble [365 x 3]>
#  9  1988   259   259   263   274 group1 <tibble [365 x 3]>
# 10  1989   261   270   273   285 group1 <tibble [365 x 3]>
# ... with 98 more rows
```

Gather the group columns together and then `nest` the data. Now each row contains one year - group combination and the data column stores the columns `doy`, `val` and `indicator` for this particular combination. This makes it easier to calculate the `rle` in the next step for all year - group combinations.

```
mat_new <- mat_new %>% 
 mutate(group.rle = map(data, ~ .x %>% filter(indicator) %>% pull(val) %>% rle), 
        max.group.rle = map_dbl(group.rle, ~max(.x$lengths[.x$values == 1])))

mat_new

# A tibble: 108 x 9
#     year    D1    D2    D3    D4  group               data group.rle max.group.rle
#    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <chr>             <list>    <list>         <dbl>
#  1  1980   230   231   233   236 group1 <tibble [365 x 3]> <S3: rle>             1
#  2  1981   235   238   242   242 group1 <tibble [365 x 3]> <S3: rle>             2
#  3  1982   236   242   243   246 group1 <tibble [365 x 3]> <S3: rle>             1
#  4  1983   243   245   247   249 group1 <tibble [365 x 3]> <S3: rle>             1
#  5  1984   247   248   249   250 group1 <tibble [365 x 3]> <S3: rle>          -Inf
#  6  1985   249   250   253   263 group1 <tibble [365 x 3]> <S3: rle>             1
#  7  1986   250   250   255   269 group1 <tibble [365 x 3]> <S3: rle>             1
#  8  1987   255   258   259   269 group1 <tibble [365 x 3]> <S3: rle>             2
#  9  1988   259   259   263   274 group1 <tibble [365 x 3]> <S3: rle>          -Inf
# 10  1989   261   270   273   285 group1 <tibble [365 x 3]> <S3: rle>             2
# ... with 98 more rows
```

With two calls to `map` we can get the maximum rle for each group. In the first call, each `tibble` in the `data` column is filtered by the values stored in the `indicator` column, then the `val` column is extracted (with `pull`) and then finally `rle` is applied to these values.

In the second `map` call, the `rle` stored in the `group.rle` column is filtered by your conditions (only lengths of values 1) and the `max` is calculated. As this returns a numeric vector of length 1, I use `map_dbl` to directly store the result as such.

Note, this call will produce warnings, as not all groups contain the value 1 and thus the maximum has no non-missing arguments after the filtering.

```
mat_new  %>% 
  select(year, group, max.group.rle) %>% 
  spread(group, max.group.rle)

# A tibble: 36 x 4
#     year group1 group2 group3
# *  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1   1980      1   -Inf      1
# 2   1981      2      1   -Inf
# 3   1982      1   -Inf   -Inf
# 4   1983      1   -Inf      1
# 5   1984   -Inf      1   -Inf
# 6   1985      1   -Inf      2
# 7   1986      1      3      1
# 8   1987      2   -Inf      1
# 9   1988   -Inf   -Inf      2
# 10  1989      2      1      3
# # ... with 26 more rows
```

To have a better look at the results, I only select the columns `year`, `group`, `max.group.rle` and then use `spread`, to spread the groups into separate columns. Now we have one line per year with the relevant information.